# App with Flutter/Dart and GetX: ListView.builder does not update itself with new values from database

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-listview

I have programmed an app with Flutter/Dart and the GetX framework. On the HomeScreen the content from the database (ISAR DB) should be displayed in the form of card widgets. If you click on the FAB in the HomeScreen, a form is loaded in a new screen, in which you can output the data for a new CardWidget.
My problem now is that when I restart the app in the emulator, as on a real device, no records (i.e. no cards) are displayed - if I change the screen and return or, in the emulator, perform a hot refresh, the cards are displayed.
The same behavior is shown when creating a new database entry: If you return to the HomeScreen, the new entry is only displayed there after a screen change or a Hot Refresh.

I assume from this behavior that the HomeScreen is not provided with updated data - although I had actually already taken this into account, as the code below should show. Maybe someone can help me out.I assume from this behavior that the HomeScreen is not provided with updated data - although I had actually already taken this into account, as the code below should show. Maybe someone can help me out.

home_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

[imports of widgets]
import '../../controllers/home_screen_controller.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final HomeScreenController homeScreenController = Get.put(HomeScreenController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CxdAppbar(title: 'appbar_01'.tr),
      drawer: const NavDrawer(),
      body: GetBuilder<HomeScreenController>(
        builder: (homeScreenController) {
          if (homeScreenController.isLoading.value) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            final allCardEntitys = homeScreenController.allCardEntitys;

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: allCardEntitys.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CxdCardWidget1(
                  id: allCardEntitys[index].id,
                  title: allCardEntitys[index].title,
                  tsCd: allCardEntitys[index].tsCd,
                  imageBytes: allCardEntitys[index].imageBytes ?? [],
                  bgColor: Color(allCardEntitys[index].bgColor),
                  fontColor: Color(allCardEntitys[index].fontColor),
                  dividerColor: Color(allCardEntitys[index].dividerColor),
                  borderColor: Color(allCardEntitys[index].borderColor),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: const CxdFloatingActionButton(),
    );
  }
}
```

home_screen_controller.dart:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../services/entities/card_entity.dart';
import '../services/isar_service.dart';

class HomeScreenController extends GetxController {
  IsarService isarService = IsarService();

  RxList<CardEntity> allCardEntitys = RxList([]);

  RxBool isLoading = true.obs;

  Future<void> getAllCardEntitys() async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      final cardEntitys = await isarService.getAllCardEntitys();
      allCardEntitys.assignAll(cardEntitys);
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getAllCardEntitys();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using GetBuilder to update the state of a widget manually from your controller, you have to do it with update().

In your case, just use it like this:

```
 Future<void> getAllCardEntitys() async {
try {
  isLoading.value = true;
  final cardEntitys = await isarService.getAllCardEntitys();
  allCardEntitys.assignAll(cardEntitys);
  update();
} finally {
  isLoading.value = false;
}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and correct answer! Small note: a simple update(); is enough, the method does not need to be executed on the instance variable: allCardEntities.update(); => update(); Now everything works smoothly!